# MS Access + SQL Server front end concatenation problem (#NAME)

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

When I link an SQL Server table to MS Access, I have an issue with concatenation of the SQL Server table/view columns.

I'm used to be doing this in Access: `=[FirstName] & " " & [LastName]`

However, when I do this with data linked from SQL Server, I get `#NAME` in the text field every time.

I tried to create a local dummy table in Access and the concatenation works without issues.

I also tried to type the concatenation in SQL Server format: `=[FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName]`, without success.

My current workaround is to create all concatenations directly in the SQL View definitions, but this is quite limiting and I would like to be able to do concatenations directly in Access.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you aliasing that field in the query and binding the text box to the alias?

Comment: Not necessarily, it doesn't work with any field linked from SQL Server

Comment: What versions of Office, SQL Server, and ODBC do you run, please?

Comment: Both variations of your concatenation work for me: I can't reproduce this problem.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue yesterday. This morning I can't.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a new bug in Access

I linked to a SQL table and added 2 text boxes to a form  one an integer and one text

on the integer one =[field] & "b" works on the text field it fails.

even just =[textfieldname] throws an error

A workaround i found is to add firstname and lastname text boxes and rename them txtfirstname and txtlastname then add a third text box and give the datasource property = [txtfirstname] & " " & [txtlastname]

irritating as this used to work